# How do I create a spinner with custom id values?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to create a custom spinner and populate it with strings and id values.  Ultimately I will pull the values from a database, but I need a working example of a spinner with custom id values before I get to that step.

My goal is to create a spinner with custom values such as (position: 1, id:56, value: "food"), (position: 2, id:77, value: "bank") but I can't figure out how to specify the id value, only the text and position.

I've only tried some basic examples from tutorial videos and cannot find anything relating to setting the id, I have a basic spinner with custom string values working.

I expect to show only the text values from my list, but use the id I have assigned when using the selected value from the list.

Comment: what is the type of the data you retrieve from db and how do you save the id/value

Answer (score 2):

You could Create a list of Pairs like this

```
val list = listOf(
               Pair(56, "food"),
               Pair(77, "bank")...
           )

//or create data class for it

data class Data (val id: Int, val value: String)
val list = listOf(
               Data (56, "food"),
               Data (77, "bank")...
           )
```

And then based on position just get from list the Pair id like

```
list[position].first

// or using data class

list[position].id
```

And put string values you need to the spinner

Remember to create list of Pairs in the same order of values as spinner is filled.

Answer (score 0):

After much more research I found a solution to what I was looking for that works well for me.  I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter for the spinner and putting the data from the database into a Cursor.  So long as the Cursor has the primary key field labeled as "_id" it works perfectly.

This all goes in the activity file:

```
var cCursor = db.readCategoryForSpinner()
val adapterCols = arrayOf("Name")
val adapterRowViews = intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1)
val cAdapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cCursor, adapterCols, adapterRowViews, 0)
cAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
sp_CategorySpinner.adapter = cAdapter
```

Here is the sql to fill the cursor:

```
fun readCategoryForSpinner() : Cursor{
    val db = this.readableDatabase
    val sql = "select " + COL_PK_CATEGORY + " _id, " + COL_NAME + " from " + TBL_CATEGORY
    val c = db.rawQuery(sql, null)
    c.moveToFirst()
    return c
}
```

Lastly this is how I'm getting the value when I need it, in my case it's when a button is pressed:

```
var category = sp_CategorySpinner.selectedItemId.toInt()
```